# How to tell lapply to wait for each step to finish

Tags: r, function, eval, lapply

Hello I want to run the following code:

```
library(readxl)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)

data<-read_excel("Time Series/Items.xlsx", col_types = c("date", "numeric"))

gkuniforecast = function(data, Np, Ncolumn, tsfreq, model) {
  ## Preparation
  N = ceiling(Np*nrow(data))
  x=pull(data,Ncolumn)
  train.x = ts(x[1:N], frequency=tsfreq)
  test.x <- ts(c(rep(NA, N), x[(N+1):NROW(x)]), frequency=tsfreq)
  plot(train.x)

  ## Models
  str1=paste0("m_",model," = ",model,"(train.x)")
  str2=paste0("f_",model," = forecast(m_",model,", h=NROW(x)-N)")
  str3=paste0("plot(f_",model,")")
  str4="lines(test.x)"
  str=list(str1,str2,str3,str4)
  lapply(str,function(y) eval(parse(text=y)))
}

gkuniforecast(data, 0.75, 2, 12, "ets")
```

When I run each line one after the other it works. When I run it all together, I get the following error:

```
 Error in forecast(m_ets, h = NROW(x) - N) : object 'm_ets' not found
```

This is step 2 in the lapply. I suspect it is because the object "m_ets" is not created because the evaluation of str1 is not finished, yet str2 starts and it can't find it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that each iteration of lapply has its own environment. The objects created by evaluating `str1` is NOT accessible when you evaluate `str2`. Easiest solution without changing the design of your process or hacking with global environment assignment is to just use a `for` loop. *apply functions are run sequentially and are just less verbose versions of `for` loops with their own environments.

Comment: Hi VLo, thanks for the answer. I solved the problem by pasting all lines in one variable with ";" in between, so eval stops at each line, execute and then move on!